# HQL select query on Parent object and on List

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have class structure as following

```
class ABC {
abcid;
name;
listOfXYZObjects;
}

class XYZ {
xyzid;
name;
}
```

Now I have configured above classes in hbm file. There is some data already stored in DB. I have abcId and xyzId with me and want to fetch only name fields of both classes in single HQL query.

Can any one guide me for above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume your ABC is College and XYZ is Student. Using Criteria, we can get college name and student name as follows.

```
Criteria c = s.createCriteria(College.class,"clg");
c.createCriteria("students", "s");
c.add(Restrictions.eq("id",new Integer(1)));
c.add(Restrictions.eq("s.id", new Integer(1)));

ProjectionList properties = Projections.projectionList();
properties.add(Projections.property("name"));
properties.add(Projections.property("s.name"));
c.setProjection(properties);

List l=c.list();
Iterator it=l.iterator();
while(it.hasNext())
{
    Object ob[] = (Object[])it.next();
    System.out.println(ob[0]+"--------"+ob[1]);
}
```

Output:

Hibernate: select this_.name as y0_, s1_.name as y1_ from College1 this_ inner join Student1 s1_ on this_.id=s1_.colg_id where this_.id=? and s1_.id=?

SCASC College--------Student1

Answer (score 0):

If you have configured your hbm such that XYZ class is related to ABC class, the retrieval would be as if you are retrieving only from class ABC.

For example : `getHibernateTemplate().load(ABC.class, someABCId);`

Hbm for ABC  :

```
<class name="ABC" table="abc_table" mutable="false">
    <cache usage="read-only"/>
    <id name="abcId" column="id">
        <generator class="increment"/>
    </id>
    <property name="name" column="name"/>
    <list name="listOfXYZObjects" lazy="true" >
        <key column="abc_id"/>
        <index column="id"/>
        <one-to-many class="XYZ"/>
    </list>
</class>
```

Comment: Thanks for replay. I have already done this configurations. Actually I don't want to load ABC/XYZ object. Only I want is name field from ABC and XYZ. Can you suggest any HQL query?

Answer (score 0):

Use below stated hql query.

```
select new map(a.ABCname , b.XYZname) 
from ABC a, XYZ b 
where a.abcid = "+abcid+" and b.xyzid = "+xyzid+"
```

where in from clause is `ABC` pojo class and `XYZ` pojo class. Here name fields in both class should have different name. Or you can also use with out `new map` clause.

But using `new map` clause would be lot easier to you.

Hope this helps you.

Kush